# State updates but react component does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the next react code inside a render function:

```
         {this.state.info}
         <MyComponent index={0}
              selectedInfo={this.state.info} 
         />
```

if I pass a string to MyComponent like:

```
         <MyComponent index={0}
              selectedInfo={"Hello"} 
         />
```

then I will see Hello. However, if I use:

```
         {this.state.info}
         <MyComponent index={0}
              selectedInfo={this.state.info} 
         />
```

I will see nothing even if {this.state.info} prints Hello (i.e. this.state.info == 'Hello'). I suspect this is a problem related with /react's rendering system but i have no idea how to trace this.

In the beginning this.state.info is ''. After an axios call that takes like 2-3 seconds this state is updated but MyComponent does not reflect that change even when {this.state.info}  shows hello (i.e. this.state.info got updated by the axios call using setState)

Any suggestions?
Thx

Comment: where is `this.state.info` changing?

Comment: In the beginning this.state.info is null but this info becomes updated through the execution of componendDidMount using an axios call to a database. This axios call takes some time to end. But after this.state.info is updated MyComonent does not update

Comment: Are you updating your state using `setState`? React won't know that the state has changed unless you use `setState`, and changing it directly (`this.state.info = 'something'`) won't cause a re-render.

Comment: I am using setState. As a consequence of this command {this.state.info} prints Hello but that state value seems to not be passing to MyComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because a component doesn't render when props change, but only when its state changes.

A solution may be to check for a change in props in componentWillReceiveProps, and to call setState if render should be done.

Comment: @Juan Mendes, you are right. The answer has benn updated.

Comment: Inside the code for MyComponent I used the componentWillReceiveProps and I made run the staring instructions in componentDidMount all over again inside the componentWillReceiveProps. I still need to learn more about react.

Comment: all those starting instructions were executed just after the setState that updated the value for info inside MyComponent

Answer (score 1):

Is not easy to say what exact problem is cause you didnt post enough code...but here is a working example, i believe doing what you trying to do...ultimately like other guys have said, just need to update state via "this.setState()" and listening components will pick up the update...

```js
const MyComponent = ({selectedInfo, index}) => {

return (
   <div style={{border: '1px solid black', padding: '10px'}}>
       <h4>{selectedInfo}</h4>
       <p>{index}</p>
   </div>
)
}

class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectedInfo: 'intial', count: 0};
    this.btnPressed = this.btnPressed.bind(this);
  }
  
  btnPressed(){
      this.setState({selectedInfo: 'button pressed => '+this.state.count, count: this.state.count+1});
  }

  render() {
  
  return (<div>
            <MyComponent index={0}
                      selectedInfo={this.state.selectedInfo}/>
                      
           <button type="btn" onClick={this.btnPressed}>State Change working</button>
          </div>)
                      
  
  }
}

console.log(document.getElementById('app'));

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
</div>
```